# What are some remote places to live with reliable (wired) high-speed broadband internet?

Tags: where-on-earth, internet

I'm absolutely fascinated by the small, multi-colored fishing towns along maritime regions in the Northern Atlantic (Canada, Greenland, Iceland, Norway).  Since my work could technically be done remotely, my only requirement would be access to reliable (wired) high-speed broadband internet.

Any thoughts on some remote towns/villages that might qualify?  Ocean-side is not a requirement.  Probably a reasonably democratic government would be though.  Maybe Canada, Europe, US, Australia, NZ...

Comment: It looks like there are Internet cables running to Greenland: [Guardian](http://image.guardian.co.uk/sys-images/Technology/Pix/pictures/2008/02/01/SeaCableHi.jpg). I can’t tell if all of these cables are for Internet, but here is another map: [Submarine cable map](http://submarinecablemap.com/).

Comment: [This site](http://explorer.netindex.com/maps) shows broadband speeds in various cities. No data for Greenland, but Iceland appears to have fast Internet. Australia appears to have slow Internet, according to that page.

Comment: If Japan is sufficiently democratic for you, a remote island in Okinawa such as for example Yonaguni or Taketomi could fit your bill (although even in mainland Japan, most places outside the major urban centers could feel remote enough).

Comment: Then travel from country to country! That's what I've started a couple of years ago and it served me very well.